# I'll pick you up/carry you on my back

Tags: spoken-english

A kid falls down and gets hurt, so her mother says:

> I'll pick you up on my back.

Or

> I'll carry you on my back.

What should be used: "pick up/carry"? Do both of them sound equally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Carry" sounds much better, but in most cases I would expect to use "piggy-back" or something similar.

If you really want to go with the 'pick up' theme, then I would use "I'll put you on my back"

Comment: Can you please give me an example for "piggy-back"?

Comment: "I'll give you a piggy-back."  or maybe:  "I'll give you a piggy-back ride."

Comment: And what about: "I'll piggyback you."?

Comment: Will piggy-back be more common?

Comment: "I'll piggy-back you" would normally be said by the person about to be carried, not by the carrier. Piggy-back should be recognised by any native speaker, though I think the USA have mangled it in to "pick-a-back"